# Use PHP webservice in iPhone app

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, json, web-services

I have developed a webservice in PHP. It uses the MySQL database. In this, I have used JSON. I want to fetch data from this webservice in my iPhone app. I have used a function which has one parameter. How can I use this in the iPhone?

Webservice:

```
<?php

echo getdata($_REQUEST['lastupdate']);

function getdata($lastupdatedate){

    $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';



    $obj = json_decode($json);

    //print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345



    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","un","pwd");



    if (!$con)



    {



    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());



    }

    //print_r($con);



    mysql_select_db("roster", $con);







    $query = "select * from rates where LastUpdated = '".$lastupdatedate."' order by LastUpdated limit 1";

    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query);

    //print_r($rs);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){

    $record[] = $row;

    }



    $data = json_encode($record);



    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    return $data;

}

?>
```

I am requesting the URL: `http://domain/t1.php?lastupdate=2012-09-01 01:00:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create an request for `http://domain/t1.php?lastupdate=2012-09-01 01:00:00` and then parse your response JSON.

Depending on how your code should function (onload or based on some user action) your code should function similar to this example from [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

Basic code snippets:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURLValue];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
          withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

        options:kNilOptions 
        error:&error];

    NSArray* JSONResultValues = [json objectForKey:@"yourKey"]; //2

    NSLog(@"Results: %@", JSONResultValues); //3
}
```

Comment: I can't understand, in url link , what should I pass? my url is:http://domain/t1.php?lastupdate=2012-09-01 01:00:00"    in which 2012-09-01 01:00:00 is my input parameter

Comment: NSString *myvalue = @"2012-09-01 01:00:00"; NSURL *yourURLValue = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWIthFormat: @"domain/t1.php?lastupdate=%@",myValue]];   // You could create different URLs each taking the appropriate parameter value.

Comment: sir when I am doing NSLog(yourURLValue);