# How to use XML web service on iPhone with JSON

Tags: iphone, xml, json, web-services

I want to make an simple XML call from specific URL in iphone,but at the time of calling I dont get the updated result everytime, I already checked in the URL but still I am not getting the actual result,

Hear is .m controller code

```
//This is SOAP calling
NSString *postString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    "<GetCountries xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\"/>\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>";


//this is calling from URL wia above SOAP    
    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tempURL] retain];
    NSString *postLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCountries" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection * myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [myConnection start];
    NSLog(@"%@Testing ",myConnection);
    [request release];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PHP webservice in iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672717/use-php-webservice-in-iphone-app)

Comment: This link might help http://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=using+webservice+in+iPhone&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=mBf-UOrPIYjWrQfP24HgBQ Along with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Any PHP script can be called from `NSURLConnection`. Here's an example of how you can do it:

PHP

```
<?php

    print json_encode(array('MyKey' => 'value123'));
?>
```

Objective-C

```
NSData *myReceivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/path/to/api"]]];
NSError *jsonParseError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myReceivedData options:0 error:&jsonParseError];

if (jsonParseError == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Value of MyKey: %@", [jsonObj objectForKey:@"MyKey"]);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"JSON Parse error: %@", jsonParseError);
}
```

Feel free to change the synchronous request to using delegation for an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is depends on Your convenience.
That is your web services is in JSON Format or XML format,Depends on That You may parse that and use the response.

Comment: for posting better answer you must attach some Json and XML parsing method with your answer its good practice for you.